# Strange error when trying to install npm on a Mac

Tags: node.js, npm

When trying to install npm on mac os x 10.6.6 with Xcode 3.2 I get the following error. How can I resolve this?

```
MacPro:juggernaut fred$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3902  100  3902    0     0   4114      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7898
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.22.tgz

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/read-json.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/bin/read-package-json.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
0.2.5

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/read-json.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/bin/read-package-json.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/read-json.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/bin/read-package-json.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
! [ -d .git ] || git submodule update --init --recursive
node cli.js cache clean

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
make: *** [uninstall] Error 1

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.53508/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
It failed
MacPro:juggernaut fred$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a little backwards as you are missing a package when trying to install the package.

A work around might be manually installing gracefull-fs
https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are running an older version of node. The latest npm requires node v0.4 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you installing node and npm with these packages: https://sites.google.com/site/nodejsmacosx/

That way you make sure node and npm matches.

Uninstalling your current nodejs version might be a good idea.